# What font is used for the Hearthstone logo?

Tags: font-identification, logo

Any ideas on the font used for the text "Hearthstone" not the "Heroes of Warcraft" part?

[image: HearthStone logo]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like this match:

[LHF UNCIAL CAPS](http://www.fontarsiv.com/en/font/indir/lhf-uncial-caps)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/11581528154#4) on the Hearthstone forum suggests that it is Bliz Quadrata. It is far from exactly the same, but has similar characteristics. It was possibly used as a starting point then heavily modified for the logo.

[image: Bliz Quadrata Font Sample]

The font can be downloaded in WOFF format [here](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/static/fonts/bliz-quadrata.woff?v=58-11) then converted to TTF using [this tool](http://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-ttf).

Comment: *Bliz* Quadrata? I presume that’s a variant of Friz Quadrata created for Blizzard products?